# plot most 20 frequent words

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, arabic-support

here im trying to set the most frequent words with plot ,  but I'm facing a problem because the language is Arabic and it does not match the format

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
sns.barplot(x="word", y="freq", data=word_counter_df, palette="PuBuGn_d", ax=ax)
plt.show();
```

i have tried ast with decoding but it does not match them with plot

```
import ast
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
sns.barplot(x="word", y="freq", data=word_counter_df.apply(ast.literal_eval).str.decode("utf-8"), palette="PuBuGn_d", ax=ax)
plt.show();
```

word_counter_df looks like :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
      word  freq
0   الله    6829
1   علي     5636
2   ان      3732
3   اللهم   2575
4   انا     2436
5   صباح    2115
6   اللي    1792
7   الي     1709
8   والله   1645
9   الهلال  1520
10  الا     1394
11  الخير   1276
12  انت     1209
13  يارب    1089
14  يوم     1082
15  رتويت   1019
16  كان     1004
17  اذا     994 
18  لله     982 
19  اي      939
```

it reutrn empty graph with this erorr :

> ValueError: ('malformed node or string: 0     الله  \n1     علي   \n2 
>   ان    \n3     اللهم \n4     انا   \n5     صباح  \n6     اللي  \n7
>   الي   \n8     والله \n9     الهلال\n10    الا   \n11    الخير \n12
>   انت   \n13    يارب  \n14    يوم   \n15    رتويت \n16    كان   \n17
>   اذا   \n18    لله   \n19    اي    \nName: word, dtype: object',
>   'occurred at index word')

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: sorry i have updated my question with erorr

Comment: please provide an excerpt of your `word_counter_df` dataframe

Comment: sure I have updated them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas' built-in [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) function:

```
word_counter_df.plot.bar(x="word", y="freq")
plt.show()
```

---

**Update for connected Arabic letters**

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
word_counter_df['disp'] = word_counter_df.word.apply(arabic_reshaper.reshape).apply(get_display)
word_counter_df.plot.bar(x="disp", y="freq")
```

[image]

The same with seaborn (version 0.9.0) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daHCq.png).

Comment: thank you, dear as you know Arabic latter connected together and this is my main problem, i have tried to search about something can solve this arabic_reshaper.reshape for plot